# odoo 11 can't create unbalance journal entry

Tags: python, odoo

I want to create journal entry if state == 'open', but when I try that I have this issue, could you help me please?
This code is working in version 8 but it is not in version 11.

```
def create_journal_entry(self):
    move_pool = self.env['account.move']
    move_line_pool = self.env['account.move.line']
    name = "Advance payment: %s"%(self.employee_id.name)
    debit_account_id = self.debit_id.id
    credit_account_id = self.payment_method.id
    #MOVE CREATE
    move_data = {
        'journal_id': self.payment_method.id,
        'ref': name,
        'company_id': self.company_id.id,}
    move_id = move_pool.create(move_data)
    #DEBIT LINE CREATE
    debit_line = {
        'move_id': move_id.id,
        'name': name,
        'partner_id': self.employee_id.address_home_id and \
                        self.employee_id.address_home_id.id or False,
        'account_id': debit_account_id,
        'debit': self.need_amount,
        'credit': 0.0}
    debit_line_id = move_line_pool.create(debit_line)
    #CREDIT LINE CREATE
    credit_line = {
        'move_id': move_id.id,
        'name': name,
        'partner_id': self.employee_id.address_home_id and \
                        self.employee_id.address_home_id.id or False,
        'account_id': credit_account_id,
        'debit': 0.0,
        'credit': self.need_amount}
    credit_line_id = move_line_pool.create(credit_line)
    return move_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating separate jounral entry line you have to setup vals for debit and credit line then create jounral entry record. This will solve your problem

Comment: Can anyone please elaborate answer a bit more?